# Importing unfinished modules

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm building a personal module of functions, generic functions for my scientific work.

It's not finished so I would like to keep it in it's development folder for the time being without installing it like you install every other modules with pip, etc.

Now, I also need to work on other non-related projects but still need the functions.

My question is, having those 2 projects in completely independent folders, how do I import one to use in the other?

thanks

**EDIT:** Just another quick one. If both were inside their respective folder but with the same root. Would there be a better/easier way to do this?

Comment: Add the folder to your Python path and you can import it normally.

Comment: Why do people put answers in comments?

Comment: @NedBatchelder: Because I'm lazy and don't want to write up a complete answer...

Comment: @Blender: it's your rep, dude! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the directory containing your module (let's call it `functions.py`) into the PYTHONPATH environment variable.  Then you'll be able to use `import functions` to get your functions.

Pip also seems to have support for this:  `pip install -e src/mycheckout` for exxample, but I don't quite understand the ramifications of that.

Comment: I see. It worked well, thank you!

Just another quick one.

If both were inside their respective folder but with the same root. Would there be a better/easier way to do this?

Comment: You could make your folders importable, but unless they are *just* python code, I wouldn't do that.  Add whatever folders you need to PYTHONPATH, and keep things clean.

Comment: Tks for your help. Will do that.